# English (or other European) translations of Pali Canon

Tags: pali-canon, modern-world, teaching, terminology, learning-materials

Perhaps this should be closed as [a 'shopping' question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/139866), but maybe translations take a long time to make and therefore there are not too many of them, and they don't go out of date quickly.

The English texts I use seem unreliable. For example:

- One book I have (using a 1925 CE translation) has a translation which (because it uses an abstract noun "the lovely") [I had thoroughly failed](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/4053/compassion-to-friends-stepping-in-vs-letting-them-learn-on-their-own#comment5397_4055) to understand.
  In that case, [the 'Access to Insight' translation](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn45/sn45.002.than.html) was clearer (using concrete nouns like 'with people' and 'with friends' instead of abstractions like "with what is lovely").
  So I have been using **Access to Insight**.
- However when I wanted the Samuddo Sutta, the [Access to Insight version](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.187.wlsh.html) is (in my opinion) relatively very inadequate compared to [this **Buddha Vacana** version](http://www.buddha-vacana.org/sutta/samyutta/salayatana/sn35-229.html).

I only found these using Google, i.e. I have no expertise about what translations exist.

- Can you recommend **any (single) specific translations**?
- Can you give **any survey of what (many) is available**?
- Or should I ask about **translators** instead of translations (I'd prefer 'the best' translation rather than the 'historically-first' translation)?

Even if there are too many, are there **great/classic resources** that any Anglophone should know?

- **Printed** books would be on-topic, though I'm warned that such things might be [ten times the size of a bible](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/4019/254).
- **Online** or (at least) **digital** references might be convenient. For example the side-by-side (hyper-linkable) translation feature found on the *Buddha Vacana* site helped me understand (by linking to the Pali word) what it meant when it said "mental phenomena".
- A resource for any **European** language (English, French, German, etc) would be interesting
- Google Translate doesn't do Pali or Sanskrit, but if there's a (free or affordable) semi-competent **machine-based** translator (accurate although not poetic or idiomatic), that might be good (though it may be hoping too much, to hope for the existence of such a thing yet).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I personally use the following translations:

- Paper copies of Bhikkhu Bodhi's translations of Nikayas (for example [Majjhima](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/086171072X)) for nice smooth English rendition.
- [Access To Insight](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/) for quick and convenient search.
- [Dharmafarer](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/sutta-titles-2) for in-depth analysis.

When in doubt, I do my own translation with a dictionary ([Sanskrit](http://spokensanskrit.de/), [Pali](http://dsal.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/pali/), I also use a number of Pali-Russian dictionaries). For this, [Sutta Central](http://suttacentral.net/) is a good source of well-formatted Pali texts (it also has translations but I don't like their renditions).

Answer (score 2):

If I want to compare several English translations I go to Obo:
http://obo.genaud.net/backmatter/indexes/sutta/sutta_toc.htm