# English translation of the Samyutta Nikaya

Tags: reference-request

Looking for suggestions on an English translation of the Samyutta Nikaya in printed book form other than Bhikkhu Bodhi's version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SuttaCentral](https://suttacentral.net/) has translations by Ven. Sujato (and other translations).

And there are [Piya Tan's translations](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/sutta-titles-2/samyutta-nikaya) with his commentaries hosted on a site called "The Minding Centre" (formerly called "The Dharmafarers").

Also (according to [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/26982/254)), Obo's web site [links to several translations](http://obo.genaud.net/backmatter/indexes/sutta/sn/04_salv/idx_41_cittasamyutta.htm) if you want to compare them.

And the [Buddha Vacana](http://www.buddha-vacana.org/sutta/samyutta.html) web site is one of my favourites, it only translates some of the suttas but translates in depth, i.e. with the English and Pali in parallel (which you can also get with Ven. Sujato's translations, especially if you enable "Activate Pali word lookup" and "View original text with translation" in the Text settings).

Comment: Perhaps also the Pali Text Society (PTS) have a translation.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'll have a look through the links you provided. I'm really in need of an inexspensive paperback print edition. Bhikkhu Bodhi's book is good but it is to heavy and a bit pricey to put it through the paces of a carry-around-book. :D TU  ☸

Comment: Apologies, I missed "in printed book form" in the question. I think his books are online as PDFs, [here](http://lirs.ru/lib/sutra/Connected_Discourses_of_the_Buddha(Samyutta_Nikaya).Vol.I.pdf) and [here](http://lirs.ru/lib/sutra/Connected_Discourses_of_the_Buddha(Samyutta_Nikaya).Vol.II.pdf), if that's any use to you (i.e. if you have a portable digital device already).