# How do you write Anicca (Impermanence) in Pali script?

Tags: impermanence, pali

I'm looking to get a tattoo and have anicca written in Pali in several places.  Can you help me with how to write this in Pali script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no "Pali script" as such, is there? i.e. Pali is written using various scripts (or "[writing systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pali#Writing)") -- including Sinhalese, Khmer, Roman, etc.

Comment: Who, if knowing about anicca, would beauty his ugly, decaying body with a tattoo and pull such truth into not-seriousness... harm himself and wast his past merits...

Comment: "The essence of practice is remembrance, whether its remembering to come back to the present moment or recalling the truth of impermanence" - ANdrew Holoceck || . This tattoo is my structure for remembrance!

Comment: @AriCuadra There was a comment requesting you to share if you finally discovered and chose Anicca in a certain script. In this case, you can post an answer with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pāli was in [oral tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_tradition), so pāli had no its own script. However, pāli can be [written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing_system) by most of the indo-europian script instead.

Therefore, the best tattoo in Buddhism is reciting the Sutta in pāli, it is the [beginning of all meditations](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/read_rm.php?B=5&A=10684&h=Maggasaccaniddesava%E1%B9%87%E1%B9%87an%C4%81,%C4%81cariyassa%20santike%20ugga%E1%B9%87hitv%C4%81%20v%C4%81c%C4%81ya%20punappuna%E1%B9%83%20parivattento&modeTY=1#hl).

Anicca is anicca (अनिच्‍च; อนิจฺจ) without number&gender-definition.

It is aniccā (अनिच्‍चा; อนิจฺจา), aniccāni (अनिच्‍चानि; อนิจฺจานิ) as plural.

It is aniccā (अनिच्‍चा; อนิจฺจา), aniccaṃ (अनिच्‍चं; อนิจฺจํ), anicco (अनिच्‍चो; อนิจฺโจ) as singular.

It is mostly used as an adjective, and its noun often is plural.

"Sabbe saṅkhārā aniccā (सब्बे सङ्खारा अनिच्‍चा; สพฺเพ สงฺขารา อนิจฺจา)" is common widely used.

Comment: Thank you Bonn.  This was extremely helpful!

Comment: Which scripts are these?

Comment: @ChrisW It's devanagri, अनिच्‍च, and Thai, อนิจฺจ.

Answer (score 0):

You might try searching for "anicca pali images" in Google. This will get you exactly what you asked for. However, consider the following experience.

When I went to India I travelled to Varanasi (yes, the one in the suttas). I asked for a henna tattoo of "gate, gate, parasamgate, bodhisvaha". And they looked at me and said. What on earth is that?

So I told them it was the Heart Sutta. And they looked at me and said what on earth is that?

So I told them it was a Buddhist Sutta. And they said, "oh. The Buddha.".

They asked me if Sanskrit was fine, and it was.
I got my tattoo and it was very very fine.

Later that year I related this wonderful experience to my monk friend. He laughed and said, "The Buddha didn't write the Heart Sutta."

So now I just study the EBT's and don't worry about tattoos.

To study the suttas, I use [SuttaCentral Voice](http://50.18.90.151), which is a companion website to [SuttaCentral](http://suttacentral.net). SuttaCentral Voice is designed for the visually impaired (I have AMD and cannot read printed material).  The search box is used just like Google's, but only searches the EBT Pali Canon as hosted on SuttaCentral. In this way, we can search for any phrase such as "root of suffering" and browse to our hearts content. Our hearts are all slightly different, so what you type will depend on you.

Perhaps start witn [anicca](http://50.18.90.151/scv/index.html?r=0.997187525778374#/?iVoice=0&ips=4&lang=en&maxResults=5&search=anicca&showId=false&showLang=0).

:pray:

Comment: What EBts have you studied, and would recommend me to start with?

Comment: @AriCuadra thanks for the suggestion. I have added a link.

Comment: @AriCuadra See also [English translations of Pali Canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/4111/254) and [Chronological or other sequence for beginners](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4112/254)