# Sources for the Whole Tipitaka

Tags: the-buddha, tipitaka, pali, yuttadhammo

q:

> Can someone name the books in the shelf of Yuttadhammo in his videos
>   or all the books in the Tipitaka and sources to get them in English?
>   or at least what has been  translated to english?

Comment: [English (or other European) translations of Pali Canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4109/254)

Answer (score 1):

Please visit:
http://buddhadust.net/backmatter/indexes/sutta/sutta_toc.htm
This is the index page to all the suttas contained on the site.

This site is focused on the 4 Nikayas, and has:

All the Nikayas in the original Pali: both the PTS version and the BJT version, and a version that combines both;

All the Pali Text Society translations: one version in the html format, one a PDF of the originals (likely what you see in the bookshelf).

All the translations of Bhikkhu Thanissaro.

All the freely released translations of Bhikkhu Bodhi.

A great collection of very early translations as well as quite a few from 'lesser-known' translators, including myself.

All the translations are linked to the Pali and to all the other translations available.

The PTS translations and the Pali are mostly (not entirely) unabridged.

The PTS translations and the Pali are mostly (not entirely) broken down to their phrasing for clarity of meaning.

PS: For a good deal in purchasing the hard-cover books (recommended) join the Pali Text Society. Members get a free book every year and a 20% discount on purchases.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the Sutta in Sutta Central.

https://suttacentral.net/

You can by the Tipitaka from Wisdom publication. Be aware they quote prices from USD.