# Starting studying again

Tags: study

Let me explain. I have met, got enchanted and started to slowly study Buddhism on my own quite some years ago. But then time passed and life consumed me. I have never abandoned the beautiful and deep perspective on reality that doctrine taught me. But over time you get still and staggered; and life begin to rot your way if you don't keep it fed and healthy. Well, I am talking In my case. I feel that I'm losing my path and I deeply want to grow again in peace and understanding. In this world so void of physical masters and lonely, buddhist teachings have given me great relief and energy to fight on.

So, to the point: may any of you please recommend me a good reading to start meeting and discovering teachings again? If I may add please, if you know of something not too heavy or obscure... Started reading the bodhisharyavatara, which is beautiful but get a bit dense as you follow, so I can't read much at a time and don't understand much neither.

Buddhism scriptures and texts are so huge in numbers that you kinda feel lost in it. I think I would resume it like this: a great reading, no matter the school or the time.

I deeply thank you for these place and for your time and help. Yours,

David

Comment: Do you want to read more from the tradition you know already, or from another? Theravada suttas, Mahayana, Zen, maybe Tibetan? Classic or modern? Topical (on any particular topic)? Quite a lot to choose from, as I'm sure you know. What can you say or ask that would inform an answer's selection?

Comment: Well, that's a bit part of the point, Buddhism scriptures and texts are so huge that you kinda feel lost in it. I think I would resume it like this: a great reading, no matter the school or the time.

Comment: A quick search `where to start` or `books` on this site reveals some of the questions asked related to this. I think you need to do a fair bit of searching and trial & error to see what fits **your** reading style best.

Answer (score 1):

At least with the Pali suttas, start with the first three sermons:

1. https://suttacentral.net/sn56.11/en/bodhi + https://suttacentral.net/sn45.8/en/bodhi
2. https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.059.mend.html
3. https://suttacentral.net/sn35.28/en/bodhi

Then basic moral teachings, such as:

1. https://suttacentral.net/mn61/en/horner
2. https://suttacentral.net/sn55.7/en/sujato
3. https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.nara.html
4. https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.1.08.amar.html

[In the Buddha's Words An Anthology of Discourses from the Pali Canon](http://urbandharma.org/pdf2/InTheBuddhasWordsBookPreview.pdf) by Bhikkhu Bodhi is a good compilation (although take care with Bhikkhu Bodhi's often sectarian footnotes).

Answer (score 1):

My nephew gave me a pocket edition of *Zen Flesh, Zen Bones* for Christmas -- it's literally "pocket", it's 12x8x2 cm, but, surprisingly readable (good typeface, Shambhala).

I haven't read it in years -- before I found this site I had only read that of Buddhism (several times of course), and *Three Pillars of Zen*, and the *Dhammapada*, and a few modern things -- including some edition of the "[traditional legend](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/bps-essay_32.html)" -- which were well enough, but not enough, so, I can't *entirely* recommend them.

After I found this site I asked these questions ...

- [English (or other European) translations of Pali Canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4109/254)
- [Chronological or other sequence for beginners](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4112/254)

... and that's been great, for study.

For one reason I've read most of what's been posted on this site only.

One person said, I've forgotten who or when, that they studied Zen for a while but then they studied the 'earlier' (or at least, the 'Theravada') doctrine too, and then Zen made more sense to them too.

Anyway -- I opened the *Zen Flesh, Zen Bones* when I was given it, like it was yesterday or so, and it fell open on a page or story, one of the many which, I remember well:

> **31 -- Everything Is Best**
>
> When Banzan was walking through a market he overheard a conversation between a butcher and his customer.
>
> "Give me the best piece of meat you have," said the customer.
>
> "Everything in my shop is the best," replied the butcher. "You cannot find here any piece of meat that is not the best."
>
> At these words Banzan became enlightened.